# Оптимизация работы с большими списками

Tags: python

Написал очередной велосипед по генерации sitemap. Конечно, можно было бы взять готовые модули, но это не моя история. Дело даже не в велосипеде, а в реализации. По сути есть 2 списка, с которыми работаем:

1. urls - ссылки в очереди
2. visited - проверенные

Всё хорошо, когда на сайте 200 страниц. Но когда их больше 15000, то процесс длится часами, а python забивает 384 МБ памяти.

Есть ли какие более интересные методы хранения данных (не бд), которые можно использовать в нашем случае? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Непонятно что вы делаете. В обычных случаях для экономии памяти используется генераторы для экономии памяти. Да и что делать часами на 15000 элементах тоже не ясно ни разу.

Comment: Вот код для большей ясности. [https://github.com/Haikson/pysitemap/blob/master/pysitemap/crawler.py](https://github.com/Haikson/pysitemap/blob/master/pysitemap/crawler.py)Вопрос не в работе часами, т.к. это больше от канала зависит, скорости загрузки данных. Другое дело, когда каждый раз после парсинга страницы проверяются все элементы.

Comment: Хорошо, задам вопрос иначе:
Есть два списка A и B. Каждый раз, при добавлении элемента в список  B, проверяем, входит ли он в списки  A и B. На это и тратим время.

Comment: Вы сравниваете два списка поэлементно. Да, тут будет квадратичная сложность. Простой вариант с set уже подсказали, но можно держать список отсортированным и проверка одно элемента будет за логарифм.

Но в любом случае вначале нужно профайлером пройтись. Может там память и время тратит парсинг самой страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, если честно, так и не понял, что у вас жрет столько памяти. Но по вопросу ответ такой: `set()` - самая быстрая имплементация проверки на вхождение.

Comment: И почему я о сетах всё время забываю? Спасибо. Тестирую.

Comment: Ну, а память - не знаю. Списки такой длины должны занимать не больше 6 МБ. Остальное - пока загадка.

Comment: Тестирование с сетами закончил. Весь процесс занял 24 минуты вместо 46. Прогресс налицо.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответам и комментариям других участников посоветую изучить загадочный асинхронный мир.
Ссылки для ознакомления: [раз(eventlet)](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#web-crawler), [два(eventlet)](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#producer-consumer-web-crawler) и [три(gevent)](http://www.gevent.org/).

За счет того, что запросы на скачивание страниц сайта, в отличие от текущего Вашего кода, будут выполняться почти одновременно асинхронно, а не по очереди, суммарное время на выполнение всего скрипта будет значительно уменьшено.

Сразу предупрежу, если много запросов будут идти одновременно на один и тот же хиленький сайт, то Вы можете его попросту заDDOSить и положить, поэтому заранее советую продумать этот момент, ограничивая каким-либо образом количество одновременно висящих запросов на один сайт.